# How to use sonar TFVC plugin?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, tfvc

I want use the TFVC plugin with sonar. 
I have copied the file `sonar-scm-tfvc-plugin-2.0.jar` in `Sonar\extensions\plugins`.
I use the following config `sonar.properties` :

```
sonar.scm.enabled=true
sonar.scm.provider=tfvc
sonar.tfvc.username=my Tfs UserAccount
sonar.tfvc.password.secured=My TFS password
```

When I run a sonar analysis on the command line `c:sonar.net-runner.cmd`, 
the analysis is successful.

But on the web side, all issues are not assigned....

Is there something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube version 5.x+ will automatically assign issue to the last committer on the line if:

- It is a new issue that has been introduced since the last analysis
- It was possible to match the SCM user to a SonarQube user

So, if you did an initial analysis of your project, then enabled the SonarQube SCM TFVC plugin, and redid an analysis, none of the issues are new, and so it is expected for all of them to stay unassigned.

Start by verifying that you get the SCM data from TFVC properly imported into SonarQube:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dinesh !

It's a little bit tricky to configure but it works very fine now.

Yes, the SCM data are propely imported into SonarQube.

Thanks